# Cómo obtener atributo de la una sesión Java, Spring

Tags: java, string, aplicación-web, spring, session

Quiero crear una variable final, pero obtener su valor de una sesion iniciada, por ejemplo

```java
final static String variable = (String) new HttpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("codigoVerificacion");
```

Espero pueda ayudarme, ya que ese código marca error.

Comment: que error te marca?

Answer (score 1):

No se porque haces `new HttpServletRequest` cuando el `request` ya deberia estar definido

```
String codigoVerificacion = (String)request.getAttribute("codigoVerificacion");
```

Comment: como asigno ese valor, si el request se define, pero que valor toma?

Comment: El request deberia venir por parametro

Comment: quizás con algun anotacion de Spring pueda defir el valor

Comment: @WaSoM de donde especificamente estas intentando obtener ese valor?

Answer (score 1):

En Spring, puedes utilizar **@SessionAttributes**, para meter primero el objeto a la sesión, como a continuación se muestra:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"estudiante"})
public class Three {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        EstudianteDTO estudiante = new EstudianteDTO();
        estudiante.setNombre("Juan");
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hola");
        model.addAttribute("estudiante",estudiante);
        return "holamundo";
    }

}
```

Este es el DTO:

```
public class EstudianteDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5801289994733718288L;
    private String nombre;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Y para obtener el atributo **estudiante** de la sesión con **@SessionAttributes** y **@ModelAttribute** en otro Controller de la siguiente forma:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"estudiante"})
public class Obtener {

    @RequestMapping(value="/obtener.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleRequest(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute("estudiante") EstudianteDTO estudiante){
        String datoNombre = "Nombre Estudiante:"+estudiante.getNombre();
        model.addAttribute("datoNombre", datoNombre);
        return "hola";
    }

}
```

para utilizarlo en un jsp, como se muestra a continuación:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HelloWorld page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hola: ${estudiante.nombre}
</body>
</html>
```